# How to visualize horizontal bar-chart without sorting the bars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization

I want to plot a horizontal bar-plot, which I do like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

def plot_results(title, freq, labels):
    #  create the figure
    matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 15})
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4))
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.115, right=0.88)

    pos = np.arange(len(labels))
    rects = ax1.barh(pos, freq, align='center', height=0.8, tick_label = labels)

    ax1.set_title(title)

    ax1.set_xlim([0, 1])
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(11))
    ax1.xaxis.grid(True, linestyle='--', which='major', color='grey', alpha=.25)

    rect_labels = []
    # Lastly, write in the ranking inside each bar to aid in interpretation
    for i in range(0, len(rects)):
        # Rectangle widths are already integer-valued but are floating
        # type, so it helps to remove the trailing decimal point and 0 by
        # converting width to int type
        rect = rects[i]
        width = freq[i]
        rankStr = labels[i]

        # The bars aren't wide enough to print the ranking inside
        if width < 40:
            # Shift the text to the right side of the right edge
            xloc = 5
            # Black against white background
            clr = 'black'
            align = 'left'
        else:
            # Shift the text to the left side of the right edge
            xloc = -5
            # White on magenta
            clr = 'white'
            align = 'right'

        # Center the text vertically in the bar
        yloc = rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2
        label = ax1.annotate(rankStr + " (" + str(freq[i]) + ")", xy=(width, yloc), xytext=(xloc, 0),
                            textcoords="offset points",
                            ha=align, va='center',
                            color=clr, weight='bold', clip_on=True)
    plt.show()
```

Once I input some parameters:

```
freq = [0.48, 0.40, 0.07, 0.05]
labels = ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4']
plot_results("Plot title", freq, labels)
```

I get the following result:

[image]

The bars seem to be sorted automatically. I want the bars to appear at the exact order the labels are in the list (starting from 'Label 1' at the top, and ending with 'Label 4' at the bottom). How do I turn off this automatic sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not "sorted", the trick is that the bars are drawn from bottom to top.

To remedy, either invert the order of your data, or easier, change the direction of the y-axis:

```
freq = [0.48, 0.40, 0.07, 0.05]
labels = ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(labels, freq)
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]